# Compute $\int_{-a}^a \ln \left( \frac{a + \sqrt{a^2+ x^2}}{-a + \sqrt{a^2 + x^2}} \right) \, dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int_{-a}^a \ln \left( \dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2+ x^2}}{-a + \sqrt{a^2 + x^2}} \right) \, dx = \, ? $$

I tried by substituting $x = a \tan\theta$ but wasn't able to go much further . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Start integrating by parts; then, let $x=a \sinh(y)$ could help.

Comment: Assume that $a$ is positive.  Don't we have to take into account that the denominator vanishes for $x=0$?

Answer (score 2):

To solve:

$$\text{I}=\int_{-\text{a}}^{\text{a}}\ln\left(\frac{\text{a}+\sqrt{\text{a}^2+x^2}}{\sqrt{\text{a}^2+x^2}-\text{a}}\right)\space\text{d}x$$

Use integration by parts, to get:

$$\text{I}=\left[x\ln\left(\frac{\text{a}+\sqrt{\text{a}^2+x^2}}{\sqrt{\text{a}^2+x^2}-\text{a}}\right)\right]_{-\text{a}}^{\text{a}}+2\text{a}\int_{-\text{a}}^{\text{a}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{{\text{a}}^2+x^2}}\space\text{d}x$$

---

I used: $\int f\space\text{d}g=fg-\int g\space\text{d}f$, where:

$$f=\ln\left(\frac{\text{a}+\sqrt{\text{a}^2+x^2}}{\sqrt{\text{a}^2+x^2}-\text{a}}\right),g=x,\text{d}g=\text{d}x,\text{d}f=-\frac{2\text{a}}{x\sqrt{\text{a}^2+x^2}}\space\text{d}x$$

---

Now, use:

- When $\text{a}>0$:
  $$\int_{-\text{a}}^{\text{a}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{{\text{a}}^2+x^2}}\space\text{d}x=\text{a}\cdot\text{arcsinh}(1)$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
 Use [Trigonometric substitution](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/trigsub/trigsub.html), $x=a\tan y\implies dx=a\sec^2y\ dy$

Finally writing $\cos y=u$ use [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html)

$$\dfrac{1+u}{(1-u)u^2}=\dfrac Au+\dfrac B{u^2}+\dfrac C{1-u}$$

and find $A=1, B=C=2$

Finally $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dy}{1-\cos y}=\int\dfrac{\csc^2\dfrac y2}2dy=-\cot\dfrac y2+K=-\dfrac{1+\cos y}{\sin y}+K$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use integration by parts:

$$\int_{-a}^a \ln \left( \dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2+ x^2}}{-a + \sqrt{a^2 + x^2}} \right) \, dx = $$$$ \left[x\ln \left( \dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2+ x^2}}{-a + \sqrt{a^2 + x^2}}\right) + 2a\ln(\sqrt{a^2+ x^2}+x)\right]_{-a}^a=$$
$$2a\ln\left(\dfrac{\sqrt2+1}{\sqrt2-1}\right)$$